# How to change price of product programmatically in in-app Purchase functionality?

Tags: ios, iphone, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I want to change price of product dynamically from mobile app on basis of email id through which user login.

Do Apple allow do this? If yes , Please tell me how to do this.

Answer (score 3):

Prices for in-app purchase are set through iTunesconnect.  As far as I am aware there is no API available to change prices and prices cannot be changed dynamically, only for specific periods of time (such as a 1 week "sale") or set indefinitely.

You could have multiple products registered at different price points and decide which product to display to a particular user - but be aware, the in-app purchase products are visible in the iTunes store, so your customers would be able to see all of the different price-points and products that you were selling

Comment: Can I hide particular products from showing on itunes , like show particular items and hide other

Comment: Not as far as I know.

Comment: Thanks for reply , I will add a products with different price point , and request on itunes according to user email id specific price.

Comment: No, you can't. I believe the customer can ask Apple for a refund but there are no guarantees they will provide one

Comment: You could probably collect payment on another website to provide "credit" to the users account but if you collect payment in the app for features/capability in the app then a 3rd party solution is not allowed. For confirmation you should check with apple

Answer (score 1):

I do not think apple allows to do this. You can set it using itunesconnect. Application can only retrieve the information of products. They have not provide any web call to change the information of inapp purchase product in their programming guideline.